# I am not able to use ngbAccordion methods to the child ngbAccordion

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, ng-bootstrap

```
<ngb-accordion #accord="ngbAccordion">
  <ngb-panel  *ngFor=" let children of laptop.children; let index = index" id="static-{{index}}" title="[{{children.id}}] - {{children.name}}">
    <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
        <ngb-accordion #childaccord="ngbAccordion">
            <ngb-panel  *ngFor=" let children2 of children.children; let index2 = index" [disabled]="false"   id="static2-{{index2}}" >
              <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
                  <span>&#9733; <b>[{{children2.id}}]</b> {{children2.name}} &#9733;
                    <div style="float:right; border: solid 0.3em; border-color: gold;">+{{children2.price}}€</div>
                  </span>
              </ng-template>
            </ngb-panel>
          </ngb-accordion>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>

<button (click)="accord.closeAll()">CloseParent</button>

<button (click)="childaccord.closeAll()">Closechild</button>
```

In this case Closeparent button is working fine
Not Closechild button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need get the "parents" and the "childs" accordeons. For this, you use ViewChildren.

In your .ts

```
  @ViewChildren('accord')parents:QueryList<NgbAccordion>
  @ViewChildren('childaccord')children:QueryList<NgbAccordion>

  closeAllParent()
  {
    this.parents.forEach(x=>x.collapseAll())
  }
  closeAllChildren()
  {
    this.children.forEach(x=>x.collapseAll())
  }
```

See the example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ljxbxu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE: Cap-7, it's more easy try to help if you give more clue or even you create a stackblitz